# How to Improve AMP page load times

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, load, amp-html

I have tested the following AMP article - https://www.windowstechit.com/4237/windows-10-hdmi-audio-not-working/amp/ using GTMetrix. The test link is as - https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.windowstechit.com/ifzKQuOu.

The page load time is 6.2s. I manually tested the AMP page and its taking lot more time. I also tested using PageSpeed Insights tool of Google. There also mobile score is less. The article is very lengthy with some YouTube videos embedded in it.

As a whole for my site, the AMP pages are loading slow. What is the reason.

I am using the AMPforWP plugin by Ahmed Kaludi for Wordpress. 
Is this a cause of concern for slow speed.

Answer (score 0):

AMP is not a magic pill that will instantly make your website super fast. You need to  [apply web optimization techniques](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/why-performance-matters/) . I suggest you start with a web performance test and take it from there.